# Would Django be appropriate for this project?

Tags: python, django

I'm a CS student interning at a company that needs a web app made to make looking at data much easier for the end user. I'm very new to web dev. I have experimented a little bit with HTML and CSS but I have never touched Javascript.

Anyway, my company has a web API that I have access to that returns a bunch of data points in JSON format. Upon doing some research online it seems that utilizing something like Django, Node.js, or Rails would be the best option to parse these JSON strings and return the data that I am interested in. Django seems like the best alternative because the documentation seems very good, and I know Python relatively well so the learning curve will not be too bad.

Do you guys think I have roughly the right idea so far? Would using Django to parse hundreds of JSON format strings be a good idea, and then export the data I have to HTML in some way and construct the web app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I <3 Django.

But in my opinion, Django is best suited to making objects out of data in a database. It does this using and MVC-ish structure and an Object Relational Model (ORM). I'll make some assumptions from your question:

1. your data isn't in a DB, but is a bunch of JSON strings
2. you're more interested in displaying, rather than manipulating this data

If those are true, I would think you would want front-end focused system using Javascript. That's the best at handling JSON, after all. Django or Rails would be overkill for parsing strings.

Look at Angular or Ember, et. al.

Comment: What about something like Node.js?

Answer (score 0):

**Node.js** is great for requesting remote JSON data and real-time streaming. Pair it with socket.io and real-time data just get more fun.

Take a look at [D3.js](http://d3js.org/), which use SVG to generate stunning, customized data visualizations or for simple visualizations, [Google Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/) is really simple to begin with.